# How to use where clause based on parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to have the user be able to enter multiple fields that they can filter from the database . Right now I have inputs being dynamically created when the user selects which column they want to search for.

The form submits the url

```
/sites.csv?zipcode=74656?state=newyork.
```

There may be multiple of the same fields example

```
/sites.csv?zipcode=78656?zipcode=74656?.
```

I want to be able to get all fields that have the zipcode 78656 and 74656 or state new york and zipcode 74656. Whatever the user enters and doesnt matter how many fields are sent.

How can I get these parameters and do a where clause with each one

Sites Controller

```
class SitesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        // If parameters exist 
         // do where clause
        else
         @sites = Site.all
       respond_to do |format|
                format.html
                format.csv { send_data  // if fields exist  dont use all sites @sites.to_csv }
                format.xls 
        end
    end
    private

    def site_params
        params.require(:site).permit(:latitude, :longitude, :building_height, :zoning_class, :state, :town, :zipcode, :county, :first_name, :last_name, :company_name)
    end
end
```

Index Page

```
    = form_tag("/sites.csv", method: :get) do
            #csv-modal.modal.fade{"aria-labelledby" => "myModalLabel", :role => "dialog", :tabindex => "-1"}
                .modal-dialog
                    .modal-content
                        .modal-header
                            %button.close{"aria-label" => "Close", "data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"}
                                %span{"aria-hidden" => "true"} &times;
                            %h4.modal-title Download CSV
                        .modal-body
                            .btn-group
                                %button.btn.btn-default.btn-sm.dropdown-toggle{"aria-expanded" => "false", "aria-haspopup" => "true", "data-toggle" => "dropdown", :type => "button"}
                                    Add Fields
                                    %span.caret
                                %ul.dropdown-menu.csv-selector
                                    %li
                                        %a
                                            Latitude
                                    %li
                                        %a
                                            Longitude
                                    %li
                                        %a
                                            State
                                    %li
                                        %a
                                            Town
                                    %li
                                        %a
                                            Zipcode
                                    %li
                                        %a
                                            County
                                    %li
                                        %a
                                            Building Height
                                    %li
                                        %a
                                            Zoning Class
                                    %li
                                        %a
                                            First Name
                                    %li
                                        %a
                                            Last Name
                                    %li
                                        %a
                                            Company Name

                            .input_fields_wrap
                                %div
                        .modal-footer
                            %button.btn.btn-default{"data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"} Close
                            %button.btn.btn-default{:type => "submit"} Download CSV

:javascript

    $(document).ready( function () {

        $('.table').DataTable();

        var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

        var x = 1; //initlal text box count
        $(".csv-selector > li > a").click(function(e){ //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box increment
                $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="'+$(this).text().trim().toLowerCase()+ '" class="form-control small-field" placeholder="'+$(this).text().trim()+'"/><a href="#" class="remove-field btn btn-danger remove-field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
            }
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When the same URL parameter is used, Rails combines the values in an array and assigns this as the value of the parameter in the parameter hash. Hence for the request `/sites.csv?zipcode=78656?zipcode=74656?`, the params would be:

```
params[:zipcode] #=> [78656, 74656]
```

When using `where`, ActiveRecord builds an `IN` condition for an array of values so you can pass in the `params` hash directly:

```
class SitesController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @sites = Site.where(params)
```

Comment: because the inputs are named the same the first parameter is overwritten by the second. only one zipcode shows up

Answer (score 0):

Your URL request params need to be separated with [`&`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Web_forms):

```
/sites.csv?zipcode=74656&state=newyork.
```

To pass these to a `where` query, you'll have to do something like:

```
def index
   records = []
   params.each do |k,v|
      records << k #-> ["zipcode", "state"]
   end

   @sites = Site.all
   records.uniq!.each do |param|
     @sites += @sites.where("#{param} IN ?", params[param.to_sym])
   end
```

Comment: I get undefined method each